# Class hierarchy in intellij that shows members

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is it possible to view class hierarchy in intellij along with methods. Suppose, I'd like to know in which classes along class hierarchy certain method was overriden/implemented. In eclipse I can open hierarchy panel (f4), lock on method and then it'll show me where it was overriden. How can I achieve the same thing in Intellij ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a gutter left to every method signature, you have a little icon indicating if its overriden/implemented or overrides/implements some other method.

[image]

Just hover on it to see where.

[image]

Click will let you choose implementation and jump to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Structure
```

and clicking the gearwheel select `Show Inherited`

or go to

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Hierarchy
```

Comment: As far as I know, `Structure` (also accessible via `Alt + 7`) won't tell you that. It only annotates which method in inspected class are overriding/implementing methods of a base class, not the other way.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option that you can see the members in the left side called :

```
Structure
```

[image]